# i am able to save data in my arraylist but cannot print by another method

Tags: java, arraylist

when i call my print  method from my GUI class passing parameter in print method
my print method declared in another class is able to store those value but when i try to print those value through print method then empty space is print``

```
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class StudentInfo {
    ArrayList<String> arrayOfNames = new ArrayList<>();
    ArrayList<String> section = new ArrayList<>();
    ArrayList<Integer> marks = new ArrayList<>();
    ArrayList<Long> mobileNumber = new ArrayList<>();

    public void data(String s, String s1, long s2, int s3) {
        System.out.println(" " + s + " " + s1 + " " + s2 + " " + s3);
        arrayOfNames.add(s);
        section.add(s1);
        marks.add(s3);
        mobileNumber.add(s2);
        System.out.println("\nhi");

        System.out.println(arrayOfNames);
    }

    public void print() {
        System.out.println("\n\n hi");
        System.out.println(arrayOfNames);
        System.out.println(section);
        System.out.println(marks);
        System.out.println(mobileNumber);
    }
}
```

Comment: show us some code?

Comment: Don't put your code in an image. Add it to your question.

Comment: i have posted a link with it

Comment: Post your code in the question, do not link your code.

Comment: Your `print()` method is not being called. Where you call the print method?

Comment: Also, by just calling `println(...)` on the array variable, it will print the reference to the variable, rather than its contents.

Comment: It's advisable to put your code in your question. Sharing code with links makes potential helpers navigate to another site for reference to the code which a lot of people may not want and in future the link you provided may be broken and it'll make your question incomplete.

Answer (score 1):

Only possibility is: Save data is called by one instance and another new instance called the print method, please validate this by adding default constructor in this class with debug message and confirm.